# How to track click through rate to external website using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to monitor the number of clicks on a ebanner on a website and this ebanner links to an external website.

For example, if I'm on abc.com, clicking on the ebanner leaves abc and goes into xyz.com. Google analytics cannot track this event because I do not have the GA access for xyz.com. Hence, I've created a GTM tag to track outbound link.

I have also set up a Google Analytics tag in GTM and created a goal to track this specific event. However, with the tags firing, the goal conversion I set up in GA remained 0.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Virtual Page Views, sending a "pageview" event to Google Analytics of a page that doesn't actually exist. You can do it this way:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/virtualpageview/nameofthepage')
```

This will make the pageview appears on your Google Analytics and you can use it to create Goals and/or Events.

Answer (score 0):

use UTM parameter which will get track in Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Track it with "linkClick" Event, it is pretty easy to create you have everything predefined, enter conditions that trigger fire when "Click Url" matches *xyz.com* than when you defining a tag remember what exactly you typed for event category or action. Then go to GA and create a event type goal that will match your event category. That is pretty much it

Comment: I did track it with linkClick. However, I'm unsure of what I should fill in under Goal details. Under Category, Action, Label and Value. Understand that category is the detail i've input in GTM. What about the rest?

Comment: Category should be enough, when you setting up a goal you can check it on "verify this goal" under step 3 (goal details) and it will show you if the set up is as it should be.

Comment: I've actually re uploaded the question here. Do you spot any errors?https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122742/error-tracking-clickthrough-rate-with-gtm-and-ga