# Error tracking clickthrough rate with GTM and GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to monitor the number of clicks on a ebanner on a website and this ebanner links to an external website.

For example, if I'm on abc.com, clicking on the ebanner leaves abc and goes into xyz.com. Google analytics cannot track this event because I do not have the GA access for xyz.com. Hence, I've created a GTM tag to track outbound link.

I have also set up a Google Analytics tag in GTM and created a goal to track this specific event. However, with the tags firing, the goal conversion I set up in GA remained 0. I've attached snippets of my GTM and GA below.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, you see, "action" and "label" in GTM event configuration are variables not just text as it is with "category" , i want to say that {{click url}} (from GTM event) 100% is not matching "Click" (From GA goal action) instead of "Click" there should stand actual link "xyz.com" or you can just exclude action and label from goal configuration

Answer (score 1):

Action and Label in your GTM tags are variables... and will change depending on what link is clicked (eg if you have other outbound links on your site too, then the Event Action and Event Label will vary, depending on which link is clicked.

You need to take a look at how the applicble event itself is being reported in GA when it is clicked on for site xyz.com and then enter the relevant Action and Label information into the GA Event Goal fields.